# Java more than one kind of utf-8

Tags: java, parsing, encoding, utf

I have a sort of strange problem with encoding. I'm writing a java program that reads and writes to file. Both reading and writing is set to uft-8, and it appears to work well. 
When I open the file in notepad++ and chose 'encoding' it will be set to 'utf-8', as it should. The problem is that if i choose the option 'convert to utf-8' (in notepad++) my document will be marked as dirty, and switching to hex and looking at both in diff will show a difference. 
The real problem is that the second version will not be parsed correctly. A line starting with double-slash (which should be a comment and ignored by the parser) is interpreted as "?//". Does anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it? How can there be more than one kind of utf-8?

Comment: Why would you want to convert a `UTF-8` text to `UTF-8`? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Java stores strings internally as UTF-16

Comment: nrk: The thing is, on other computers (with possibly other editors) it is stored as "the other kind of utf-8" when the files i edited.

davek: Even if java stores as utf-16 internally, that shouldn't really be a problem if i writes using utf-8 right?

Comment: What is the difference between two files? What changes? By looking at the bottom right corner of the Notepad++, you can see the file encoding. What you see there? `UTF-8` or `ANSI as UTF-8`?

Comment: If you can 'convert to UTF-8' with Notepad++ means that in fact the file is not encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Is this comment line the very first line? If so, it could be byte order mark (BOM)

Comment: I think your problem is [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: BOM. I think so too. Upvote BOM comment.

Comment: Yes, it was BOM. I switched to "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" and the first to characters of the first line in the file, "//", are no longer interpreted as "?//"
The problem is, I really would like it to be possible to open up this file using any editor (e.g. notepad), edit it and save it without causing problems. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I honestly don't understand why the Java UTF-8 decoder doesn't transparently ignore any initial BOM, but unfortunately it doesn't.

The behaviour was reported as a bug almost a decade ago, but Sun decided not to fix it, as the fix may break existing workarounds: [Bug 4508058](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4508058)

One possible workaround is to use a PushbackReade, peek at the first character and discard it if it is a BOM:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("...");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
PushbackReader pr = new PushbackReader(isr);
int c = pr.read();
if(c != 0xFEFF) {
    // not a BOM
    pr.unread(c);
}

// use pr as your reader
```